# How Works the Licence of Office Online Server

Tags: office-web-apps

Hi i have a licence of Microsoft Office 2016 Profesional Plus, and in the MVLS (Microsoft Volumen Licensing) i downloaded the Office Online Server and install in the server, works fine integrating with my sharepoint2013 but. 
Do I have to have a new license for each of the company's employees so they can view and edit documents online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each user who needs to modify documents must have an Office license, via Software Assurance or via Office 365 subscription. View-only users do not need to have a license.

You can use [User License Enforcement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx) should you have users who need view-only and those who are licensed for edit functionality. The license for editing functionality is `OfficeWebAppsEdit`.

More information can be found at the bottom of the official blog post - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2016/05/04/office-online-server-now-available/.